# Is there a way to delete the tag history in the search bar on your Tumblr profile?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-tags

In the Tumblr app, if you hit the search button on your profile a list of every tag you have used in a post will pop up.

Is there a way to delete them?

I deleted all the posts that contained the tags, but the suggestions are still there. I deleted the search bar completely on my PC but it is still there in the app.

Answer (score 2):

The answers is that deleting tag history is not supported.

I also wanted to know if this is possible, so I contacted Tumblr Support to ask them.

For reference, this is the response I got from Dave at Tumblr Community Support;

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for reaching out and asking about this.
>
> That's not supported at this time, but thanks for asking about it. I
>   contribute regularly to reports that my team puts together to make
>   recommendations to our engineers, so any time you ask for something
>   new, that’s super helpful to me. Though changes aren’t up to our
>   department, we do make sure that every suggestion gets passed along,
>   and I know that the decision-makers at Tumblr do read and care about
>   that feedback.

This is the screenshot of the email;

[image: Tumblr Support Email]